# How do I make my pictures go in rows of 4 as I am showing it using CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css, slideshow, picturegallery

```
<div class="img">   
<a target="_blank" href="slideshow/slideshow2.jpg"><img src="slideshow/slideshow2.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
</div>

<div class="img">
 <a target="_blank" href="slideshow/slideshow3.jpg"><img src="slideshow/slideshow3.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
```

That is my code that I am using. www.goparkfast.com in the pictures section if you want to see how it is set up on my site.

Comment: img { 
  max-width: 100%; 
  height: auto; }

 img.scale-with-grid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto; }

Comment: that is what I defined img as

Comment: You should have a concise title, then describe your problem with relevant code in the main post. Also edit your post rather than comment edits.

Comment: `.img { display:inline:block; }` - as by default a div is a block level element, and will span the width of its parent.

Comment: I tried what you said Nick R and it didn't work

img { 
  max-width: 100%; 
  height: auto;
  display:inline:block; }

 img.scale-with-grid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto; }

Comment: Notice the `.` before `img`, you have a `div` with a class of `img`, so the `CSS` should be applied to the `class` (`display:inline-block`) and not the `img tag`.

Comment: Also `max-width` won't work if you explicitly declare the width and height of the `<img>`

Answer (score 0):

Set containing divs to `float: left` and `width: 25%`.

Comment: sorry very noob , this is my first website lol.
img { 
  max-width: 25%; 
  height: auto;
  float:left; }

 img.scale-with-grid {
  max-width: 25%;
  height: auto; }

Comment: is that what you mean? see how I changed .img

Comment: @user3711144 Partly, do you want the images next to the lists to be in rows of 4? Add four images to one of the list and I will show you how to align them on live example.

Comment: LOL four negatives on my question? First question I asked here and idk what I did wrong. Well Mr.Linek I want them horizontal instead of vertical and when I add four more I want them to appear under and have 16 pictures, four rows of four. Then I can make as many rows as I want

Comment: Add a `div` tag inside `sixteen columns` div and move `a` tag with `img` inside that div. Now set CSS to the `a` tag to `float:left; width: 25%;`. Now set the width to the `div` tag you just created like `width: 400px` (whatever width you want).

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the images in divisions and then put a certain size of the division like 25% and lastly mark  it to float:left